# Firebase Basic Query for datetime Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write a program to check if the time selected by the user already exists in the firebase firestore or not. If it does then I navigate back to the page where they select time again.

But as of now, I am succeeded in sending the date and time to firebase and but not the latter part.

```
DateTime _eventDate;
  bool processing;
  String _time;
  bool conditionsStatisfied ;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _eventDate = DateTime.now();
    processing = false ;
  }
```

inside showDatePicker()

```
setState(() {
 print('inside the setState of listTile');
   _eventDate = picked ;
                        });
```

inside the button (SAVE):

```
 onPressed: () async {
                    if (_eventDate != null) {
                      final QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore
                          .instance
                          .collection('events')
                          .where('event_date', isEqualTo: this._eventDate)
                          .where('selected_time', isEqualTo: this._time)
                          .get();
                      final List <DocumentSnapshot> document = result.docs;

                      if (document.length > 0) {
                        setState(() {
                          print('inside the method matching conditions');
                          showAlertDialogue(context);
                        });
                      }else{
                      final data = {
                        // "title": _title.text,
                        'selected_time ': this._time,
                        "event_date": this._eventDate
                      };
                      if (widget.note != null) {
                        await eventDBS.updateData(widget.note.id, data);
                      } else {
                        await eventDBS.create(data);
                      }
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      setState(() {
                        processing = false;
                      });
                    }
                  };
```

some guidance needed on how do I resolve this issue!

Also, because of the else statement now the program won't write the date into firestore.

Comment: eventDBS.updateData comes from a package of firestoreHelper

Comment: 'selected_time ' maybe whitespace?

Comment: @jiholee        even after that no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Alot of research, I came to realize that if you send the data from calendar in DateTime format then, because of the timestamp at the end of the Date it becomes impossible to match to dates. Hence I formatted the DateTime value into (DD/MM/YYYY).

Here is the rest of the code for reference:

```
class _AddEventPageState extends State<AddEventPage> {

  String _eventDate;
  bool processing;
  String _time;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _eventDate = DateTime.now();
    processing = false ;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Please select a date'),),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      hourMinute30Interval(),
      Text('$_time'),
      ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
                '$_eventDate'),
            onTap: () async {
            
              DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(context: context,
                initialDate:  DateTime.now(),
                firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 1),
                lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 10),);
              if (picked != null) {
                setState(() {
                  print('inside the setState of listTile');
                  _eventDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(picked) ;
                });
              }
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          ListTile(
            title: Center(
              child: Text('Select time for appointment!', style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          processing
              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Material(
              elevation: 5.0,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              color: Theme
                  .of(context)
                  .primaryColor,
              child:MaterialButton(
                      child: Text('SAVE', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      )),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (_eventDate != null) {
                          AddingEventsUsingRajeshMethod().getAvailableSlots(
                              _eventDate, _time).then((QuerySnapshot docs) async {
                            if (docs.docs.length == 1) {
                              showAlertDialogue(context);
                            }
                            else{
                              final data = {
                                // "title": _title.text,
                                'selected_time': this._time,
                                "event_date": _eventDate,
                              };
                              if (widget.note != null) {
                                await eventDBS.updateData(widget.note.id, data);
                              } else {
                                await eventDBS.create(data);
                              }
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                              setState(() {
                                processing = false;
                              });
                            }
                          });
                        }
                      }
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);


 }
```

showAlertDialogue method :

```
showAlertDialogue(BuildContext context) {

Widget okButton = FlatButton(onPressed: (){
  Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,

      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => datePicker()),
    );
  });
}, child: Text(' OK! '));

AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
  title: Text('Slot unavailable'),
  content: Text('This slot is already booked please select another slot'),
  actions: [
    okButton,
  ],
);

showDialog(context: context ,
  builder: (BuildContext context){
  return alert ;
  }
);
  }
```

The hourMinute30Interval() is nothing but a Widget that returns a timePickerSpinner which is a custom Widget. [Tap here for that.](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_time_picker_spinner)

The Query that is run after passing the _eventDate and _time is in another class, and it goes as follows :

```
class AddingEventsUsingRajeshMethod {
  getAvailableSlots(String _eventDate , String _time){
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('events')
        .where('event_date', isEqualTo: _eventDate )
        .where('selected_time', isEqualTo: _time)
        .get();
  }
}
```

You can name it something prettier ;)